# How to read configuration/properties file in C?

Tags: c, file, properties, configuration

I have a .properties file having key value pairs like -

```
RegisterAE_OriginHeader = C
RegisterAE_ContentTypeHeader = application/json;ty=2
RegisterAE_RequestIdentifierHeader = /var1/R0
RegisterAE_AppendServicePathInURL = /R0
RegisterAE_ResultContent = 0
```

Now what is the efficient way of getting values of different data type (e.g. char*, integer separately) from this properties file in a c program?

I can parse using lex/yacc to identify char*/integer?

how can they be used in a c program?

I do not know which key will correspond to char*, and which one to integer.

Comment: It's pretty vague. Can you give an example of such a file you would like to parse?

Comment: Usually you know what type your properties should be.  For example a property called `WaitTimeout` probably isn't a string, and you would never store it as such.

Comment: file can be of format : 
A="hello"
B=23
C=23.5

I want values to be returned to be of type char*,int,float in the above cases.