# Properties file reading in C (no C# or C++) compiled with minGW

Tags: c, properties

I need to say that i am Newbie at C and i only wrote about 100-150 lines of code in C.

I need to read a .properties file with entries like the following:

```
Value1 = Hello
Value2 = Bye
```

I would like to get to the Values like this:

```
bla.getValue("Value1");
```

So i can work with it like this:

```
foo = bla.getValue("Value1");
bar = bla.getValue("Value2");
printf("%s - %s",foo,bar);
```

I don't need them for anything else, than printing them to the screen.

I found two questions here, which went into the right direction, but they couldn't help me in my task:
[How to read configuration/properties file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965891/how-to-read-configuration-properties-file-in-c)

[Properties file library for C (or C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874052/properties-file-library-for-c-or-c)
I tried multiple of the answers of the thread above, but either way my compiler(minGW) doesn't like one of these lines:

```
using foo::bar;
or
using namespace foo;
```

When i try to compile my code, i get an error saying:
*error: unknown type name 'using'*

This is the code where i tried to implement the given solution of the thread above:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using platformstl::properties_file;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE a,HINSTANCE b,LPSTR c,int d)
{
char *tPath, *tWindow;
char *search = " ";

tWindow = strtok(c, search);
tPath = strtok(NULL, search);
properties_file properties("%s",tPath);

properties::value_type value1 = properties["Value1"];
properties::value_type value2 = properties["Value2"];

printf("Window: %s; Path: %s; %s %s",tWindow,tPath,value0,value1);
}
```

I use a WinMain, because the programm is about finding an open Window. I haven't included those parts of the code, because they are irrelevant for my question and worked completely fine. The `strtok();` parts are working fine for me too. I need them, because the title of the window to find and the Path of the properties file are both given as commandline arguments:

> programm.exe windowtitle path/to/properties/file

As i tried with other answers, which told me to load some libraries, i got to a point, where the needed libraries didn't contain the needed header files. Some of the libraries are even for c++, which i have a restriction on, so i can't use it.

I hope that made things a little clearer, as you may know that i am not used to ask questions here. :)

Comment: This question is either off-topic or to broad. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see how your first link can't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Problem with a big Workaround.

This is my final code:

```
if(vn != NULL){
 for(i = 0; i < 1; i++){
  if(fgets(temp, BUF, vn) == NULL){
   printf("Line is empty");
   return 2;
  }
 }
 if(fgets(puffer, BUF, vn) == NULL){
  printf("Line is empty");
  return 2;
 }
 tVariable = strtok(puffer, find);
 tValue = strtok(NULL, find);
}else {
 printf("Unable to read File");
 return 2;
}
```

I just read the second Line of the given file and cut it at the `=` sign.

I know, that i need to read the second line, because the Property i need is always found in the second line of the .properties file.

I now have my wanted Value in `tValue`, so i can use it to print it out with `printf("%s", tValue)`.